# How do I use "implicit" as apply() parameter?

Tags: scala, implicit, apply

I want to do this:

```
abstract class Context {
    def getInt(id: Int): Int
}

abstract class Dependency[+T]
(val name: String, val id: Int)
extends Function1[Context,T]

class IntDependency(name: String, id: Int)
extends Dependency[Int](name, id) {
    def apply(implicit context: Context): Int =
        context.getInt(id)
}
```

But then I get an error message like this:

```
class IntDependency needs to be abstract, since method apply in trait
Function1 of type (v1: Context)Long is not defined (Note that T1 does
not match Context)
```

I understand that implicits should normally be part of the *second* parameter list, but I can't work out how to code it so it compiles, and gives the result I want.

Explanation: I'm trying to create a framework where one can define "Function" object, which can depend on other functions to compute their value. All functions should only take a single Context parameter. The context know the "result" of the other functions. The function instances should be immutable, with the state residing in the context. I want the functions to create "dependency" fields at creation time, which take the context *implicitly*, and return the value of the dependency within that context, so that accessing the dependency inside of the apply method "feels like" accessing a parameter or field, that is without explicitly giving the context as parameter to the dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you need your `Dependency` to extend a `Function`? Because if you don't, just leave the `extends Function1[Context,T]` part out and your code will work.

If you really need to extend a `Function` than I don't know of a solution in your case. But there are cases where you could try to overload the `apply` method. Like here:

```
scala> val sum = new Function1[Int, Function1[Int, Int]] {
         |      def apply(a: Int) = (b: Int) => a + b
         |      def apply(a: Int)(implicit b: Int) = a + b
         |}
sum: java.lang.Object with (Int) => (Int) => Int{def apply(a:Int)(implicit b: Int): Int} = <function1>

scala> sum(2)(3)
res0: Int = 5

scala> implicit val b = 10
b: Int = 10

scala> sum(2)
res1: Int = 12
```

Comment: That was the correct hint. I defined Dependency as a normal object and renamed apply to get, without the implicit keyword. Then, I just added a static "implicit conversion" method that takes Dependency as first parameter, and Context as implicit curry parameter. This compiles and make the context implicit on access to Dependency.

Answer (score 4):

A method may have its final parameter section marked implicit; it need not be the second section, although that is most commonly seen.

But it seems that when a subclass marks a parameter section implicit, it is no longer considered to override the method in the superclass.

```
scala> new (Int => Int) { def apply(implicit i: Int) = i }
<console>:8: error: object creation impossible, since method apply in trait Function1 of type (v1: Int)Int is not defined
(Note that T1 does not match Int)
       new (Int => Int) { def apply(implicit i: Int) = i }
           ^

scala> trait F1 { def f(a: Any) }; new F1 { def f(implicit a: Any) = () }
<console>:8: error: object creation impossible, since method f in trait F1 of type (a: Any)Unit is not defined
       trait F1 { def f(a: Any) }; new F1 { def f(implicit a: Any) = () }

                                       ^
```

The spec does not specifically mention this (§5.1.4 Overriding), so it may be an implementation restriction, or an bug.

Answer (score 2):

Its sure, that your `apply` method signature with `implicit` doesn´t conform with the signature of `Function1.apply`.
Hopefully I get your problem right, so what about (assuming that your `context` is mutable and perhaps singleton) having the implicit context injected at creation time? Is that possible in your case?

```
class IntDependency(id: Int)(implicit context: Context) extends Dependency[Int](id)
```

But then I wonder (and still was wondering before) what to do with the `context` argument at the `apply` method.

Comment: I'm not sure yet if it will be mutable. Probably yes, but definitely no singleton, because then I couldn't multi-thread on the same instances of my functions. So this won't work for me.

Comment: ok, singleton doesn´t matter. But if not mutable then the state at creation time is frozen and you can´t rely on the current one at apply invocation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working solution:

```
abstract class Context {
    def getInt(id: Int): Int
}

abstract class Dependency[+T]
(val name: String, val id: Int) {
    def get(context: Context): T
}

class IntDependency(name: String, id: Int)
extends Dependency[Int](name, id) {
    def get(context: Context): Int =
        context.getInt(id)
}

implicit def intDep2Int(dep: IntDependency)
(implicit context: Context): Int =
dep.get(context)
```