# Where should I define implicit arguments in the apply method?

Tags: scala

I would like to define `two implicit parameters` in the apply method as the following:

```
object WsGraph {

  def apply(logger: Logger, sink: Sink[Message, Future[Done]])
           (implicit system: ActorSystem, implicit executor: ExecutionContextExecutor) {

  }
}
```

But the compiler does not allow this. How to do it correctly?

Comment: did not understand your question but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401635/how-do-i-use-implicit-as-apply-parameter

Comment: Take out the 2nd `implicit`. Everything in that parameter group is implicit if the word "implicit" starts the group.

Comment: You probably need an `=` before the `{` or this won't return anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add **one** keyword `implicit` at the beginning of the second argument list and all arguments on it will be implicit:

```
object WsGraph {      
    def apply(logger: Logger, sink: Sink[Message, Future[Done]])
               (implicit system: ActorSystem, executor: ExecutionContextExecutor) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple implicit parameters do not work.
It should be like:

```
object WsGraph {

  def apply(logger: Logger, sink: Sink[Message, Future[Done]])
           (implicit system: ActorSystem, executor: ExecutionContextExecutor) {

  }
}
```